# Difference between $("#orderedlist").find("li") and $("#orderedlist li")

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between:

```
$("#orderedlist").find("li")
```

...and...

```
$("#orderedlist li").
```

When would one be used over the other?

Comment: You would use `$("#orderedlist").find("li")` if you already have a reference to `$("#orderedlist")`.

Comment: Speed is probably a key difference, but also with `.find()` you can get a new subset that you can then `.end()` to go back to the full set.

Comment: `.find` seems to be faster http://jsperf.com/find-vs-inline

Comment: @Vega: Check out the Opera result. Their `querySelectorAll` is very fast.

Comment: @Vega: If the selector is evaluated by Sizzle, then they are evaluated from right-to-left, i.e. first all `li` elements are selected and then those which are not a descendant of `#orderedlist` are removed. Or maybe `querySelectorAll` works similar (I don't know). From that perspective it makes sense IMO.

Comment: I find `$("#orderedlist li")` easier to read, so I'd I'd use that unless I needed (or already had) a separate reference to `$("#orderedlist")`. Performance testing does show one as faster than the other, but to do the operation _once_ the difference doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, there isn't one.

Only in complicated selectors does it make sense to break them up into different methods.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#orderedlist").find("li")` is faster because it uses native JavaScript.
`$("#orderedlist li")` will be slower because it invokes Sizzle when you pass in a selector.
Both do the same thing anyway.

Comment: Does it use Sizzle? Are you sure it does not use `document.querySelectorAll` (where available)?

Comment: The jsperf is so inconsistent across browsers, I guess you're right.

Answer (score 0):

I will use .find() in this situation:

```
$("#orderedlist").show().find("li").css("color", "red");
```

But if #orderedlist is visible, and I just wanted to directly change the

's color to red, I would use

```
$("#orderedlist li").css("color", "red");
```

I think it's just a matter of what are you doing.